# Simple variable assignment using lex

Tags: regex, lex

I have a configuration file as follows.

```
e_type=15                                                                                                                                                                           
HID=h_ID
```

I use the following lex file to recognize the pattern.

%option noyywrap

```
%{

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

%}

%%
e_type=[0-9]+               { printf("Keyword: %s\n", yytext);}
[^\t\n\r]                     {   }   
%%

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    if(argc > 1)
    {   
        FILE *file;
        file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if(!file)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s \n", argv[1]);
            exit(1);
        }
        yyin = file;
    }   
    yylex();
}
```

I compile the program as follows

```
 flex test.l ; gcc lex.yy.c -o test
```

I run the program.

```
./test tmp.conf
```

The output that I get is

```
Keyword: e_type=15
```

I want to separate out the value of 15 and assign it to a variable.How do I do that.

Comment: It looks like you need to use `[0-9]+` regex since you have only one number in the file.

Comment: @stribizhev - this is just a sample value. I plan to add more values in future.